# Using primary keys with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've been **struggling** for the past few days with **primary keys** and the last version of Ember Data.

I first read how to do it on the [Breaking Changes file on GitHub](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md), but it's apparently outdated. I tried [several](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e44b07b142ca046e6b0a) [other](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/54f9fa49959c593036a8) [ways](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f7d31e0819cf1618abda) (with the help of Peter Wagenet on IRC), but none of them seem to work.

I would like to make `slug` my primary key on my model, and also since I'm working with MongoDB, I would like to use `_id` instead of `id`.

Has anyone figured out how to do this? My underlying problem is that model records get loaded twice when I do several `App.MyModel.find()` on the model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Ember Data 1.0 beta you define `primaryKey` on the respective serializer.

For the entire app

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

For a single type

```
App.FooSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

You will still refer to it as `id` on the model, but Ember Data will serialize/deserialize it to `_id` during transfer.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/635/edit

Read More about it here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#property_primaryKey

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to make slug my primary key on my model, and also since I'm working with MongoDB, I would like to use _id instead of id.

Use the adapter's `map` API to specify the attribute that should be used as primary key:

```
App.Adapter.map('App.Person', {
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

See [serializer.js api docs](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/serializer.js#L79) for detail. If you need to further customize how the records id is serialized, use the `addId` hook described [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/serializer.js#L394).

Since ember-data is still under active development, documentation on this feature is somewhat limited and may change before 1.0 release. In the meantime refer to the ember-data test suite to see examples of this in action. For example:

- [mapped primary keys are respected when serializing a record to JSON](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/json_serializer_test.js#L186) demonstrates how an _id attribute will be included in json when a record is saved
- [mapped primary keys are respected when materializing a record from JSON](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/json_serializer_test.js#L205) shows how JSON with _id attribute will be transformed into a record with the correct id

Comment: Last 2 links should point to: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/tests/integration/serializers/json-serializer-test.js

Answer (score 1):

In case the solution suggested by Nikita doesn't work (didn't for me using revision 11 of ember-data), here is how I changed the primary key when working with the RESTAdapter:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    serializer: "App.MySerializer"
});

// notice we extend the RESTSerializer, not Serializer!
App.MySerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: function(type) {
        return '_id'; // you get it...
    }
});
```

I'm aware that this probably won't help the OP anmore but I still post it as it may be helpful for some of you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend your adapter like this:

```
   App.RESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
      init: function() {
        this._super();

        this.map('App.MyModel', {
          primaryKey: "_id"
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [Ember-Data 1.0.0-beta.6](http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.0.0-beta.6/ember-data.prod.js) in my application and the _id posed a problem in [Ember 1.4.0](http://emberjs.com/) for me too. Here's what I've done to solve the problem, assuming the returned JSON array is nested in the root property "people":

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalizeHash: {
        people: function(hash) {
            hash.id = hash._id;
            delete hash._id;
            return hash;
        }
    }
});
```

This is, of course, an application-wide serializer but you can limit it to a specific path with something like `App.MyPathSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({ ... });`