# DS.RESTAdapter.map is undefined

Tags: javascript, model, ember.js, primary-key, ember-data

So, i have been trying to find out how to set different primary keys on different models in ember, and i have seen people using `App.Adapter.map` to achieve this.

However whatever i try, it seems that nothing in ember has a map function this is what i have tried.

```
App.Adapter = DS.Adapter.extend();     // .map === undefined
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(); // .map === undefined
```

I have tried much more than that but all seems `undefined`.

I have also done stuff like this

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: App.Adapter.create()
});
```

Doesn't change anything.

Does anyone know why this could be, I have been hard-coding the `primaryKey` now i need to change it to individual models.

Current hard-coded

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
   primaryKey: 'username'
});
```

Goal:

```
App.Adapter.map('App.Person', {
  primaryKey: 'username'
});
```

This is where map is seen 
http://ember-website.thomasboyt.com/api/data/modules/data-serializer.html -- **4th code block down**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15480105/1907358

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify custom serializers per model like this:

```
App.PersonSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({ primaryKey: 'username' });
App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({ primaryKey: 'foo' });
```

Comment: That's excellent, any idea's why `App.Adapter.map` is `undefined`?

Comment: Did you ever find out why .map was undefined? I'm having the same problem now.

Comment: @AdamCharnock Not sure, but I would guess that examples with .map were using old versions and Ember has deprecated it in favor of the custom serializers shown here.