# Ember data changing primaryKey for a model from id to something else

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

Currently I have a model setup like this

```
App.Specialty = DS.Model.extend({
    //specialty_id: attr(),
    name: attr()
});
```

It has a primaryKey being returned from the json api called `specialty_id` instead of `id` (what ember data probably expects).

So not fiddling with anything ember data gets two objects where one it uses the id as whatever parameter and the second one it gets the right object but has id as undefined.

How can I let ember data know that it should be searching for `specialty_id` instead?

Comment: I think you can get the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821980/using-primary-keys-with-ember-data

Answer (score 10):

For the entire app

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

For a single type

```
App.FooSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

You will still refer to it as `id` on the model, but Ember Data will serialize/deserialize it to `_id` during transfer.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/635/edit

Read More about it here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#property_primaryKey